# My while loop is not breaking after my interrupt updates in C

Tags: c, embedded, arduino-uno

I am implementing simon says as a small weekly project for school. Using arduino Uno, I'm making 10 levels each level has an extra pattern inside. example: level 1: [1], level 2: [1,2], etc... I have three buttons on my shield. the interrupts work and everything is gucci. My problem here is in this snippet

```
bool readInput(uint8_t pattern[], uint8_t length)
{
    sei();
    uint8_t current = 0;
    while (current < length)
    {
        btnPushed = false;
        while (!btnPushed)
        {
#ifdef DEBUG
            _delay_ms(1);
#endif
        }
        printf("here");
        cli();
        _delay_ms(200);
        if (currentPushed == pattern[current])
        {
            printf("correct, you pushed %d\n", currentPushed);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("incorrect, lets try again\n");
            return false;
        }
    }
    btnPushed = false;
    return true;
}
```

so basically I set my buttonPushed to false, and start listening for interrupts, once its true after clicking, I expect to exit the loop and check the input, however my interrupt is correct and I get visual feedback with a light that lights up once i push a button.

this is my ISR

```
ISR(PCINT1_vect)
{
    uint8_t buttonCurr = currentButton();
    if (buttonCurr != -1)
    {
        if (!btn1Pushed && buttonCurr == 0)
        {
            btn1Pushed = true;
        }
        currentPushed = buttonCurr;
        blinkLed(currentPushed, 1);
        btnPushed = true;
    }
}
```

my current button returns 0-2 for buttons that are clicked, and -1 if nothing was clicked.

this is the rest of my code, which is working pretty much

```
int currentPushed = -1;
bool won;
bool btnPushed = false;
bool btn1Pushed = false;

ISR(PCINT1_vect)
{
    uint8_t buttonCurr = currentButton();
    if (buttonCurr != -1)
    {
        if (!btn1Pushed && buttonCurr == 0)
        {
            btn1Pushed = true;
        }
        currentPushed = buttonCurr;
        blinkLed(currentPushed, 1);
        btnPushed = true;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    enableAllButtons();
    enableAllLeds();
    lightDownAllLeds();

    prepareButtonsForInterrupt();
    initUSART();
    init();

    play();
    if (won)
    {
        printf("Simon says you win");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("simon says do better");
    }
    return 0;
}

void init(void)
{
    printf("LETS PLAY SIMON SAYS\nPress button 1 to start!\n");

    int seed = 0;
    while (!btn1Pushed)
    {
        blinkLed(3, 4);
        seed++;
    }
    srand(seed);

    printf("Get ready!\n");
    btnPushed = false;
    cli();
}

void createRandomPattern(uint8_t array[], uint8_t length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand() % 3;
    }
}

void play(uint8_t pattern[])
{
    uint8_t fullPattern[MAX_PATTERN_LENGTH];
    createRandomPattern(fullPattern, MAX_PATTERN_LENGTH);
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_PATTERN_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        printf("========LEVEL %d===========\n", i);
        playPuzzle(fullPattern, i);
#ifdef DEBUG
        printPuzzle(fullPattern, i);
#endif
        readInput(fullPattern, i) ?: i--;
    }
}

bool readInput(uint8_t pattern[], uint8_t length)
{
    sei();
    uint8_t current = 0;
    while (current < length)
    {
        btnPushed = false;
        while (!btnPushed)
        {
        }
        cli();
        if (currentPushed == pattern[current])
        {
            printf("correct, you pushed %d\n", currentPushed);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("incorrect, lets try again\n");
            return false;
        }
        current++;
    }
    btnPushed = false;
    return true;
}

void printPuzzle(uint8_t pattern[], uint8_t length)
{
    printf("[ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", pattern[i]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

void playPuzzle(uint8_t pattern[], uint8_t length)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        lightUpOneLed(pattern[i]);
        _delay_ms(500);
        lightDownOneLed(pattern[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `printf`-debugging is inadequate. First of all the `"here"` printout doesn't have a newline, so even if the output is connected to a terminal it won't be printed immediately. But since you're on an Arduino it's likely that the output from `printf` is written to a serial output, and that the output will be fully buffered which means all your other output might also not be written immediately. Add a `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf` to see what happens.

Comment: As for a possible hint about your problem, you clear (disable) interrupts inside the loop, but you don't set (enable) them inside the loop. Try clearing the interrupts, assign the value of `currentPushed` to a temporary variable, and set the interrupts again immediately. Then use the temporary variable in the rest of the code. Things like serial communication is also likely disabled by disabling interrupts, so if you want your debug output you need interrupts enabled.

Comment: thank you both. I will add these and will see what happens, the button1push is just for the start of the game, can only start once button 1 is pressed, thanks .

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have a global variable that i set in the interrupts, that I use right after disabling, but I never seem to get there anyway, I deleted my printfs and debugs expect for the ones that state if im wrong or not. I just cant break out of the first empty loop

Comment: use `volatile` keyword for variables changed in interrupt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

btnPushed is defined as `bool btnPushed = false;`.

So when you write:

```
    while (!btnPushed)
    {
#ifdef DEBUG
        _delay_ms(1);
#endif
    }
```

Nothing in the loop will change `btnPushed` so there is no point for the compiler to ever check `btnPushed` again. So what the compiler sees is this:

```
    if (!btnPushed)
        while(true)
        {
#ifdef DEBUG
            _delay_ms(1);
#endif
        }
```

You have to tell the compiler that the value of `btnPushed` will change unexpectantly when the interrupt fires by using:

```
volatile bool btnPushed = false;
```